# HAProxy using 100% CPU 200 concurrent connections

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, haproxy

I've recently started to load test my app and found that `HAProxy` for some reason is not able to handle a lot of concurrent connections.

Im only using `HAProxy` to load balance my SSL traffic, for non-ssl (99% of my traffic is ssl) i use nginx.

I have tested my setup on blitz.io and when sending traffic to non-ssl (200 concurrent) i get no timeouts or errors. However when doing the same test over SSL (which `HAProxy` handles) i immediately get 100% CPU and requests are timing out.

This leads me to believe there is something wrong in my `HAProxy` config.

Below is my config, any ideas what could be wrong?

Oh and i am running this on a medium EC2 CPU optimized instance

My haproxy.cfg:

```
global
      maxconn     400000
      ulimit-n    800019
      nbproc      1
      debug
      daemon
      log         127.0.0.1   local0 notice

  defaults
      mode        http
      option      httplog
      log         global
      stats       enable
      stats       refresh 60s
      stats uri   /stats
      maxconn     32768


  frontend  secured
      timeout     client 86400000
      mode http
      timeout client 120s

      option httpclose
      #option forceclose
      option forwardfor

      bind        0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.pem


      acl is_sockjs path_beg /echo /broadcast /close # SockJS
      acl is_express path_beg /probe /loadHistory /activity # Express


      use_backend www_express if is_express
      use_backend sockjs if is_sockjs
      default_backend www_nginx


  backend tcp_socket
      mode        http
      server      server1     xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 check port 8080

  backend www_express
      mode        http
      option      forwardfor  #this sets X-Forwarded-For
      timeout     server      30000
      timeout     connect     4000
      server      server1     xx.xx.xx.xx:8008 weight 1 maxconn 32768 check

  backend sockjs
      mode        http
      option      forwardfor  #this sets X-Forwarded-For
      timeout     server      30000
      timeout     connect     4000
      server      server1     xx.xx.xx.xx:8081 weight 1 maxconn 32768 check

  backend www_nginx
      mode        http
      option      forwardfor  #this sets X-Forwarded-For
      timeout     server      30000
      timeout     connect     4000
      server      server1     localhost:80 weight 1 maxconn 8024 check

  listen stats :8181
      mode http
      stats enable
      stats hide-version
      stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
      stats uri /
      stats auth helloxx:xx
```

Comment: When you do the non-ssl test, what does your CPU load look like? SSL will add some overhead. Which can very depending on the size of your key.

Comment: Without SSL I am at around 10%

Comment: Changed the SSL line in HAProxy config to: `bind        0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.pem ciphers RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES:!ADH:!aNULL:!DH:!EDH:!eNULL` this helped a lot but still huge spikes in CPU

Comment: SSL by itself should not add that much overhead. What does `iowait` look like? Do you see any specific errors in your logs?

Comment: Removing some SSL ciphers will help. That was going to be one of my suggestions.

Comment: No specific errors :/

Comment: The medium box should be able to handle this kind of traffic one would think. So i dont think the hardware can be an issue here, feels like it has to be the config somewhere